# get an item selected in angular option tag

Tags: angularjs

I have an  object in  controller like this:

```
$scope.organisations = {
"id" : 1,
"name" : "organisation name"
}
```

and another object like this

```
$scope.region = {
"id" : 1,
"organisation_id" : 1
}
```

I want to show organisation name selected if the organisation.id equal to region.organisation_id.

in view I used this

```
<select
    ng-options="organisation as organisation.name for organisation in organisations track by organisation.id"
    ng-model="region.organisation"
    name="organisation_name"
    class="form-control">
</select>
```

now how can I show the organisation item selected in my region edit form?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select
    ng-options="organisation as organisation.name for organisation in organisations track by organisation.id"
    ng-model="OrganisationName"
    name="organisation_name"
    class="form-control">
</select>
```

controller should be

```
$scope.OrganisationName = $scope.region.organisation_id
```

// or

```
$scope.OrganisationName.id = $scope.region.organisation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module("app" , []);
app.controller("appCtrl", appCtrl)

function appCtrl($scope){
$scope.organisations = [{
"id" : 1,
"name" : "organisation name"
},{
"id" : 2,
"name" : "organisation name2"
}]
$scope.region = {
"id" : 1,
"organisation_id" : 1
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<select
    ng-options="organisation.id as organisation.name for organisation in organisations"
    ng-model="region.id"
    name="organisation_name"
    class="form-control" ng-selected="{{organisation.Id == region.id}}">
</select>
</div>
```